# How to scale database and Performance in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, performance

We  are facing issue with Django SQL Performance. Even setting up `CONN_MAX_AGE` setting, Connections are not closing. Following configurations we used,

> CONN_MAX_AGE: 5

Is there any place to do the configurations for performance?

Can you suggest me any Solution for multiple application servers with Single Database server architecture?

Comment: Are you sure  you are setting it correctly? Post your `settings.py` please.

Comment: yes. I am Sure. We are are getting high sql query time if we have peek load. why its happening. I am unable to find the cause for this. Even we are not using 50% of Available Database connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Persistent connections" don't close; they stay open for reuse.

Anyway, tuning that will not affect scaling and performance much.

If you have slow queries, high CPU, high I/O, discover what query is the villain; then we can discuss improving it.